# add jquery tab on MVC4 and jquery ui 1.9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs, partial-views

im trying to add a new tab on a partial view dynamically, this is my code:

**Script**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        jQuery("button").button().click(function () {
             var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
             var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
             $( "<li><a href='#tab4'>New Tab</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
             $("<div id='tab4'><p>New Content</p></div>").appendTo(tabs);
             tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        });
     });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=tabs>
<ul>
    <li><a href=#tab1>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#tab2>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#tab3>Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
    <div id=tab1>Contents of the first tab</div>
    <div id=tab2>Contents of the second tab</div>
    <div id=tab3>Contents of the third tab</div>
</div>

<button>add</button>
```

the problem, when i press the button i get this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYg0o.png]

is like hte new tab is not been aded to the tabs ande the content is loaded at the end of the tabs.

any idea?

Comment: DONE: one does not simply leaves the bundle to 1.8.4 min ui and expects 1.10 to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundle error! i updated the jqueryui libraries to 1.10 but didnt change the bundles. They still point to the old ones, that was the cause of my error